# How to read values of a child from Firebase Realtime DB?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get values from my database. However, I am unsuccessful. Here is what the DB looks like:

[image]

Here is what I tried to do, to read the values:

```
    taskRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Tasks").child(titleOfTask)

    taskRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
         if let taskDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            print("Printing ---------> ",taskDict["Description"] as Any)
         }
    })
```

but nothing happens. Ideally, I want to read both the description in a different variable and due date into a different variable.

---

Important Things to know:

- `"Tasks"` is.. you can think of it as a table name.
- Alpha, Bravo, Jalabi... etc are all `"Task Names"` or childs of `"Tasks"`
- Description, Due Date are the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching a listener to `/Tasks/$titleOfTask` in your JSON, say `/Tasks/Alpha`. That listener is asking to be called for the first **child** node of `/Tasks/Alpha`, so the `snapshot` in your code will point to `/Tasks/Alpha/Description`. When you then print `taskDict["Description"]`, you are printing the value of `/Tasks/Alpha/Description/Description`, which does not exist.

The simplest fix is to listen for the `.value` event:

```
taskRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
     if let taskDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
        print("Printing ---------> ",taskDict["Description"] as Any)
     }
})
```

Now the `snapshot` has all data from `/Tasks/Alpha`, and thus the `taskDict["Description"]` ends up being the value from `/Tasks/Alpha/Description`.